# implode function not working in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, implode

I want to store a checkbox array value by using implode function.when i stored,the database table value as Array (not a integer value show only array)

This is my view file:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div>
    <label class="form-control-label">Select Asset Type</label><br>
    <div class="border-checkbox-section">
        <div class="border-checkbox-group border-checkbox-group-primary">
            <?php $b=0; foreach($assettype as $assettype_info){ $b++;?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="assettype_name[]" class="border-checkbox" value="<?php echo $assettype_info->assettype_name; ?>" id="checkbox<?php echo $b;?>">
            <label class="border-checkbox-label" for="checkbox<?php echo $b;?>"><?php echo $assettype_info->assettype_name; ?></label>
            <?php } ?> 
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public function insertassetassign()
{           
$employee=$_POST['employee'];        
$assettype_name = implode(", ", $_POST['assettype_name']) ;  
$assign_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['assign_date']));  
$_POST['assetassign_status']='1';
$joinon=date('Y-m-d'); 
$result = $this->insert->insertrecord('assetassign');   
    if($result) 
{
    redirect('assets/assetassignment', 'refresh');
} 
}
```

My Model :

```
Public function insertrecord($Table) 
{
    $Inputs=$_POST;  
    $Inputs["joinon"]=date("Y-m-d");
    $Keys=array();
    $Values=array();
    foreach($Inputs as $Inp_key=>$inp_value) 
    {
        if($Inp_key!="submit" && $Inp_key!="PHPSESSID")
        {
            $Keys[]= $Inp_key;
            $Values[]= "'".$inp_value."'";
        }
    }
    $keys=implode(',',$Keys);
    $values=implode(',',$Values);
    $qry="insert into ".$Table."(".$keys.") values(".$values.")";
    $ack=$this->db->query($qry); 
    if($ack)  return true;  else  return false; 
}
```

I expected to store a array value as id with comma

DB shows as :

[Db shows as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEB4b.png)

Comment: what is your expected output and what are you getting can you show us?

Comment: can you remove extra space from implode which is after the comma and check again ?

Comment: can you show your model code? because I didn't find a parameter to send to model

Comment: Kinldy check my updation.

Comment: Any body please help me

Comment: have you tried to insert your data through jquery/ajax @sixthstar

Comment: No sir I am not tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified in controller to get the answer.

```
public function insertassetassign()
{           
    $employee=$_POST['employee'];        
    $assettype_name = implode(",",$_POST['assettype_name']) ;  
    $_POST['assettype_name'] = $assettype_name;
    $assign_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['assign_date']));  
    $_POST['assetassign_status']='1';
    $joinon=date('Y-m-d'); 
    $result = $this->insert->insertrecord('assetassign');   
        if($result) 
    {
        redirect('assets/assetassignment', 'refresh');
    } 
}
```